# Loop though get request and return items that are true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops

beginner question. I have a angularjs project. im using a $http.get request that return a json formatted item.

```
{ "total": 3,"items": [{"container":bla, "conf": { "id": "unique ID1"} }, {"container":bla, "conf": { "id": "unique ID2"}, {"container":bla, "conf": { "id": "unique ID3"} } } ] }
```

i want to loop through all items. currently i have this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {

      if (id === response.items[i].conf.id){
        return response.items === true;
                } else {
      }
```

this returns true like i want it to. but now I want the response to contain only the items that are true. what is the best way to do this? I think i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: `response.items.filter(i => i.conf.id === id)` ?

Comment: well there are 2 ways, if you can use es6 you can use .filter();
else you can run over and assign what ever is true to new array.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the `filter` method to find all items in your array matching a predicate (boolean condition) i.e.

```
const itemsWithId = response.items.filter(i => i.conf.id === id)
```

Refer to the filter docs here: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)**

```
let result = response.items.filter(res=>res.conf.id === "yourId");
```

Answer (score 0):

use array filter

```
let arr=[{"container":'ruy', "conf": { "id": "1"} },{"container":'bla', "conf": { "id": "2"} },{"container":'bla', "conf": { "id": "3"} }]


let id="1";
let result = arr.filter(({conf})=>conf.id === id);
console.log('result',result);
```